# Ubuntu 20 no WI-FI after every update

Tags: wireless

I have the no Wi-Fi problem. I solved it in the first place by plugin a mobile device with an internet connection and  installed third party drivers. The problem was solved, but now by every update I do the Wi-Fi wont work anymore and I need to repeat the third party driver installation after every update.

I can't provide more information from terminal because the Laptop i am talking about is a friends and we solved the problem in phone calls. Now we want to fix this issue once and for all.

Thanks for the help.

Edit:
[Here is a screenshot of the output from lsub and lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q6DA.png)

Edit2:
[Screenshot of error while doing "sudo ./dkms-install.sh"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPBZE.png)

I was going throught all the steps described in the answer below and run into this error I didn't understand. We blacklisted everything, rebooted and internet still working, but I am not quite sure if the issue is solved now or not..

Edit3:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325 for kernel 5.13.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Sat 04 Jun 2022 11:14:59 AM EDT
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.13.0-44-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-44-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_mi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_chplan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_pathtbl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_hwmp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_rson.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_btcoex_wifionly.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_odm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_rm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/rtw_rm_fsm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/pci_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_rhashtable.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_mp.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c: In function ‘napi_recv’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c:358:55: error: ‘GRO_DROP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  358 |    if (rtw_napi_gro_receive(&padapter->napi, pskb) != GRO_DROP)
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c:358:55: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: * [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: * [Makefile:1879: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-44-generic'
make: * [Makefile:2244: modules] Error 2
```

**Edit4:**
Outcome of sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 –all

```
    Warning: I do not know how to handle –all.
Error! Invalid number of parameters passed.
Usage: remove <module>/<module-version> --all
   or: remove <module>/<module-version> -k <kernel-version>
```

The outcome of the git pull

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The outcome of dkms-install.sh

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.15.0-41-generic......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.15.0-41-generic......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

Answer (score 1):

When a driver needs to be downloaded to get a wireless or other device working, there are two common methods to install the driver. The exact method is usually described in the README that is included in the downloaded driver.

The first method is, generally:

```
cd ~/Downloads/<downloaded_driver_file>
make
sudo make install
```

The make install only installs the driver for the currently running kernel; that is, the kernel version against which it was compiled. This means, as you’ve found, that at every kernel version update, from, for example, 5.15.0-27 to 5.15.0-28, after the requested reboot, the driver no longer works and must be recompiled for the new kernel version.

The second and preferred method is by DKMS or Dynamic Kernel Module Support. DKMS automagically recompiles and reinstalls without any added steps from the user. The typical process is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
cd ~/Downloads/<downloaded_driver_file>
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

However, the driver package must be specifically written to use the dkms process and include a dkms.conf file. Again, the process will be clearly outlined in the included README. Here is an example:

> Debian/Ubuntu:  `sudo apt-get install dkms`
> To make use of the **DKMS** feature with this project, just run: ```
> ./dkms-install.sh

Your question says:

> I can't provide more information from terminal because the Laptop i am
> talking about is a friends and we solved the problem in phone calls.

Without some specifics, we will be unable to offer specific instructions. If you were able to gather some data, we’d want to see if there was a dkms version of the driver. To know that, we’d want to know if this is a PCI internal wireless device or a USB device. If it is PCI, we’d want to see:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

If it is USB, we’d want:

```
lsusb
```

With this information, we’d look for a dkms version of the driver so that the recompile and reinstall would be done automatically.

Without further information, we are unable to suggest a solution.

**EDIT**: Based on the further information that you provided, I suggest that you install a dkms version of the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Blacklist the current drivers:

```
sudo -i
echo “blacklist rtl8821ce”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo “blacklist rtW88_8821ce”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

**EDIT 2**: I notice that the code has been amended in the last few days. Please do:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 --all
cd rtl8821ce
make clean
git pull
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thank you, I was asking my friend to send me a screenshot of the output from the terminal and added it to the question, maybe it helps to be more specific about what to do.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Please see my Edit2, where we were going throug all the steps and hit an error while doing "sudo ./dkms-install.sh" that was not very clear to me. Afterwards we blacklistet rtl8821ce and rtw88_8821ce. I am not sure if the issue is solved now because of the error.

Comment: The first part suggests that the module is already installed and that there is no need to install it again. The second part invites you to examine the log to see more information. Please do.

Comment: I added the make.log into the question. Thank you so much to help me through the process.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 –all gave me this error message:

Warning: I do not know how to handle –all.
Error! Invalid number of parameters passed.
Usage: remove <module>/<module-version> --all
   or: remove <module>/<module-version> -k <kernel-version>

Comment: I put an Edit4 above, still not working.

Comment: We both made a typo. It is not -all it is --all. Please try again. Also, the build process failed and invited you to check the log for details: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information." Please do! Please sow us: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log`